# React cannot read the property of undefinded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner and I am getting this error "react-dom_client.js?v=10bcf841:19407 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') at WeatherCard (App.jsx:90:34)".

```
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
import { useState } from "react";
import myImage from "./images/images.jpg";


const App = () => {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState({});
  const apiFetching = async (url) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      setApiData(() => data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Form apiFetching={apiFetching} />

      <WeatherCard data={apiData} />
    </>
  );
};

const Form = ({ apiFetching }) => {
  const [searchCity, setSearchCity] = useState("");
  const BASE_URL = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=`;

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    apiFetching(
      `${BASE_URL}${searchCity}&appid=(my api key: note code)`
    );
    setSearchCity("");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={searchCity}
        onChange={(e) => setSearchCity(e.target.value)}
        className="search-bar"
        placeholder="Enter city name..."
      />
      <button className="search-btn" type="submit">
        Search
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

const WeatherCard = ({ apiData }) => {
  const staticData = {
    coord: { lon: 97.0333, lat: 20.7833 },
    weather: [
      { id: 800, main: "Clear", description: "clear sky", icon: "01n" },
    ],
    base: "stations",
    main: {
      temp: 284.9,
      feels_like: 284.01,
      temp_min: 284.9,
      temp_max: 284.9,
      pressure: 1015,
      humidity: 72,
      sea_level: 1015,
      grnd_level: 860,
    },
    visibility: 10000,
    wind: { speed: 0.89, deg: 233, gust: 0.95 },
    clouds: { all: 0 },
    dt: 1705756015,
    sys: { country: "MM", sunrise: 1705709452, sunset: 1705749237 },
    timezone: 23400,
    id: 1293960,
    name: "Taunggyi",
    cod: 200,
  };

  return (
    <div className="card-container">
      <div className="card">
        <div className="image-container">
          <img className="weather-img" src={myImage} alt="Images" />
        </div>
        <div className="info-container">
          <p>City Name: {apiData.name}</p>
          <p>Temperature in Kelvin: {apiData.main.temp} K</p>
          <p>
            Temperature in Celcius: {(apiData.main.temp - 273).toFixed(2)} °C
          </p>
          <p>
            Temperature in Fahrenheit:{" "}
            {(((apiData.main.temp - 273) * 9) / 5 + 32).toFixed(2)} °F
          </p>
          <p>Humidity: {apiData.main.humidity}%</p>
          <p>Pressure: {apiData.main.pressure}hPa</p>
          <p>Wind Speed: {apiData.wind.speed} m/s</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

I tried asking chat gpt and goggling but it didn't work. I checked every thing but don't know there's is an error. This is the error code "react-dom_client.js?v=10bcf841:14034 The above error occurred in the  component:at WeatherCard (http://localhost:5173/src/App.jsx?t=1705834027751:95:24) at App (http://localhost:5173/src/App.jsx?t=1705834027751:23:33) at WeatherCard (App.jsx:90:34)"

Comment: Your error means that `apiData` is `undefined`  (assuming that `City Name: {apiData.name}` is where the error is pointing to). Double-check that `data` holds a value within `apiFetching` and that you're not passing `undefined`/always passing a valid value to the `apiData` prop throughout your app to `WeatherCard`

Comment: adding this solves the problem "if (Object.keys(apiData).length === 0) {
    return null; // Render nothing if apiData is empty
  }
"

Comment: If that's the case, then that implies somewhere in your code you're doing `apiData.<something>.name`

Comment: `WeatherData` takes an `apiData` prop, e.g. `const WeatherCard = ({ apiData }) => { ... }` but `App` passes only a `data` prop, e.g. `<WeatherCard data={apiData} />`, so `apiData` is undefined. Either rename the prop or access the one that was passed. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WeatherCard` component is accessing `apiData`, but your `apiData` state is being set a value only when the user submits `Form` component. What about the time when there is no form submission by the user, the `apiData` stays empty, or in other words `undefined`.

Since there is no `apiData` for the `WeatherCard` to render, it throws that error. To ensure this error doesn't occur, you can just replace `apiData.name`, `apiData.main.temp` etc. with `apiData?.name`, `apiData?.main?.temp`.

This checks if `apiData` is defined (notice the `?`) and only then accesses the properties of it. This way it won't throw the error that you're seeing because it's not trying to access something that doesn't exist at the time of accessing.